# How to make JSON keep class attributes names?

Tags: ruby, json

Is there a way to make JSON generated string keep attribute names? From this model:

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name

    def self.json_create(o)
       new(*o['data'])
    end

    def to_json(*a)
       { 'json_class' => self.class.name, 'data' => [name] }.to_json(*a)
   end 
end
```

JSON generates this string:

```
{
    "json_class": "Person",
    "data": ["John"]
}
```

but I wanted a string like this:

```
{
    "json_class": "Person",
    "data":
    {
        "name" : "John"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do it and still be able to access attributes by its name? Like:

```
person.name
```

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have edited it already, so now its OK. mikhailvs thanks for the help.

Comment: Try this: `JSON.parse(person.to_json(methods: [:name]))`

Comment: or `person.as_json(methods: :name)`

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the complete attributes instead of specifying 'name':

```
def to_json(*a)
  { 'json_class' => self.class.name, 'data' => attributes }.to_json(*a)
end
```

If you want filter to specific attributes, you can do this:

```
def to_json(*a)
  attrs_to_use = attributes.select{|k,v| %[name other].include?(k) }
  { 'json_class' => self.class.name, 'data' => attrs_to_use }.to_json(*a)
end
```

And if you just want to use 'name', then write it out :)

```
def to_json(*a)
  { 'json_class' => self.class.name, 'data' => {:name => name} }.to_json(*a)
end
```

**UPDATE**

To clarify how one might make an initializer to handle all attributes, you can do something like this:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name, :other

  def initialize(object_attribute_hash = {})
    object_attribute_hash.each do |k, v| 
      public_send("#{k}=", v) if attribute_names.include?(k)
    end
  end

  def attribute_names
    %[name other] # modify this to include all publicly assignable attributes
  end

  def attributes
    attribute_names.inject({}){|m, attr| m[attr] = send(attr); m}
  end

  def self.json_create(o)
    new(o['data'])
  end

  def to_json(*a)
    { 'json_class' => self.class.name, 'data' => attributes }.to_json(*a)
  end 
end
```

Comment: OK. But when I parse it back to assemble the Person object and try to access the name attribute that's what I get: 
`p = JSON.parse(json_str)`
`puts p.name`
`name`
`John` I wanted it to output just the value string not both. Why's that happening?

Comment: I guess this way, the attribute "name" becomes an array `["name", "John"]` when parsed back from JSON string. What am I missing?

Comment: Your `json_create` method is 'splatting' the data hash into an array of arrays using `new(*o['data'])`.  Leave out the asterisk to avoid this: `new(o['data'])`

Comment: Well, now it seems that p.name is a hash `{"name" => "John"}`. That's awkward... Still not getting what I want. Thanks though :)

Comment: Ok, so change your `json_create` method to: `new(o['data']['name']`

Comment: OK. That worked! =) In this approach I have to specify all the attribute mapping I want in `json_create` method? How could I make map all attributes dynamically? Thanks very much for yout time!